# Polyfilled React application suddenly reports that 'fetch' method is not defined

Tags: javascript, npm, isomorphic-fetch-api

In the past months I have been developing a React web application that is displayed within a ASP.NET Core web project (template of Visual Studio). The application has worked in recent months and is used by users who will display it exclusively in IE 11 (Office web add-in that uses IE 11 rendering engine). I have used the 'fetch' method extensively and did not experience problems after adding the `babel-polyfill` npm package. Unfortunately, today I received the following error:

```
'fetch' is undefined
```

The polyfill packages are still present and I am unclear as to why this error is reported suddenly. As stated above it did work before, and I am unsure what caused the situation in which the 'isomorphic-fetch' package stopped working. Below you will find the `package.json` contents. Any insight into where to look for the root cause of this problem would be greatly appreciated!

```
{
  "name": "ReactApp",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/react": "15.0.38",
    "@types/react-dom": "15.5.1",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.12",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.0.5",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "react": "15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/office-js": "^1.1.2",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.5.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "office-ui-fabric-core": "^9.3.0",
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "https://registry.npmjs.org/office-ui-fabric-react/-/office-ui-fabric-react-5.29.0.tgz"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to do an `npm install` by chance?

Comment: @MarkC. Thank you for your comment. I do not think so. I just tried it and it did not resolve the problem. Moreover, the package was still present in the node_modules folder.

Comment: Did you remove the import?

Comment: @MarkC. I am not a 100% certain what you mean. The application is a ASP.NET Core application with a React front-end. From what I understand it imports the scripts through its build process. I don't think I changed anything in its configuration.

Comment: Or do you mean an import statement in the file? Ah that could be it. Maybe the 'fetch' method used to be provided by the babel polyfill rather than the isomorphic-fetch npm package.

Comment: Correct, the import in the file

Comment: I added the import `'isomorphic-fetch';` which did help fortunately! However, I am really surprised by the fact that I did not need it previously. I think that previously the babel-polyfill package took care of this, and that I misjudged which npm package added the `fetch` method. So thank you for this solution! I am however still quite keen on figuring out why the babel-polyfill package no longer provided the `fetch` method. Maybe it is because the `fetch` method is now natively supported in most browsers.

Comment: I'm not under the impression that babel-polyfill would have added `fetch` as that is part of a web specification and not for newer JavaScript language features/syntax. I know that doesn't help, but you'd probably need to determine browser versions, native fetch support, etc. in order to prove why it was previously working

Comment: @MarkC. Yeah, I read the same so I was quite surprised. Either way, thank you for your help!